# How to find JSON attribute value using another attribute value in java

Tags: java, json, xml, parsing

I have a JSON file like below (this is a part of whole json. Actual JSON is very complex) :

[JSON file (partial)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db1nb.jpg)
In my Java class I have a MAP which contains (id,authorization) value pair. I need to check if id and authorization is matching and if not matching then I want to mark authorization value as "unauthorized".

I am using the below java code to match the id element. I want to know how to find the corresponding authorization element from JSON . so that I can verify with MAP.

[JAVA code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbFuX.jpg)

This java code is returning true or false as per correct id from MAP

Comment: You dint add the java code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Part of an MCVE is listing the code **itself**, rather than linking to an image containing it. People aren't going to want to type out your code manually! ;) Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: Add your Java and JSON code as text and not as image!